# JSPM Error on any 'jspm' command: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, jspm

After successfully installing JSPM through NPM;

```
npm install -g jspm
```

any attempt to run 'jspm' on the command line or 'jspm SOMECOMMAND' all lead to the same error:

```
C:\some\path> jspm

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\common.js:108
    if (pjson.startsWith('\uFEFF'))

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
    at exports.readJSONSync (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\common.js:108:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\global-config.js:53:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\registry.js:19:20)
```

or (another example):

```
C:\some\path> jspm registry config github

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\common.js:108
    if (pjson.startsWith('\uFEFF'))

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
    at exports.readJSONSync (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\common.js:108:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\global-config.js:53:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\registry.js:19:20)
```

It's a fresh install of Node. Versions:

```
    C:\some\path> node -v
    v6.9.1

    C:\some\path> npm -v
    3.10.9
```

**EDIT:**

In "..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\lib\common.js", if I change Line 100:

```
var pjson;
```

to

```
var pjson = null;
```

It changes the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
```

to

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
```

Does this mean that the assignment inside this try block (starting line 101) is failing and 'pjson' isn't being assigned a value?

```
try {
    pjson = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved here:

https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/2148

The problem was that my LOCALAPPDATA environment variable was empty. To fix this, I set the variable to the absolute path of the AppData folder.

i.e. C:\Users\username\AppData\Local